# Отправка сообщений в мессенджер

Tags: php, sql, вконтакте

Подскажите дилетанту, как организовать отправку сообщения из формы в вк админу (сайт интернет-магазин)?

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько способов:

1. С помощью виджета — https://vk.com/dev/CommunityMessages
2. С помощью методов API — https://vk.com/dev/messages.send